# unable to install elasticsearch plugin

Tags: elasticsearch

I've downloaded elastic search plugin from

https://github.com/downloads/spinscale/elasticsearch-suggest-plugin/elasticsearch-suggest-0.0.3-0.18.6.zip

I've unzipped the folder and I know i'm supposed to put the 3 jar files in the lib/ directory (of play itself or of the application I'm creating or that of elasticsearch). but which lib/ directory shall i put it in? also, what shall i do next. i tried to understand the documentation on the website but i didn't.
I'll really appreciate any help as I've been trying for 2 days to install this plugin. I'm using play 1.2.4

Answer (score 10):

Using current homebrew installation (March 2016 -- 2.2.0_1 version) resulted in the plugin executable not being linked, therefore i had to do:

`$ ~HOMEBREW_ROOT/Cellar/elasticsearch/2.2.0_1/libexec/bin/plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head`

Comment: Thanks!! This is also working for `elasticsearch 2.3.1`

Answer (score 9):

#### MAC OS - with brew elasticsearch base install

Install the elasticsearch package with brew :

```
brew install elasticsearch
```

Install the elasticsearch_head plugin to get a simple browser :

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/1.4.0/
sudo bin/plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head
open "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_plugin/head/"
```

[image]

Comment: Probably a small change in the API, i have ES 2.1.0 and the command was: `bin/plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head` (no dash before `install`). But your answer did the trick for me, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For `elasticsearch 2.X` you need to run the second command like `sudo libexec/bin/plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head` since the plugin was moved.

Answer (score 9):

Grab the **plugin script path** by using this command on Mac OS

`brew info elasticsearch`

[image]

Then, use the **plugin script path** to install:

`/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/2.3.3/libexec/bin/plugin install some/es-plugin`

Answer (score 8):

Download elastic search deb file from this link [elastic search](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/downloads)

and once installed then check elastic search status like **sudo service elasticsearch status**
To view elastic search index in GUI, run this command from your /usr/share directory

**sudo elasticsearch/bin/plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head**

**open "http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head/"**

Comment: As an important note: Beware of PEBKAC: The trailing / in "_plugin/head/" is NOT OPTIONAL.

Comment: Any way to install it on Ubuntu without sudo?

Answer (score 3):

Try the builtin `bin/plugin` utility:

```
% bin/plugin -url https://github.com/downloads/spinscale/elasticsearch-suggest-plugin/elasticsearch-suggest-0.0.3-0.18.6.zip -install elasticsearch-suggest
-> Installing elasticsearch-suggest...
Trying https://github.com/downloads/spinscale/elasticsearch-suggest-plugin/elasticsearch-suggest-0.0.3-0.18.6.zip...
Downloading ..............................................................................DONE
Installed elasticsearch-suggest
% find plugins/elasticsearch-suggest
plugins/elasticsearch-suggest
plugins/elasticsearch-suggest/elasticsearch-suggest-0.0.3.jar
plugins/elasticsearch-suggest/lucene-misc-3.5.0.jar
plugins/elasticsearch-suggest/lucene-spellchecker-3.5.0.jar
%
```

Answer (score 3):

In one line:

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

Answer (score 1):

For ElasticSearch 7.10 in Ubuntu:

`cd /usr/share/elasticsearch`

`sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic`